# How set up my directory to work with eyeglass on fetching modularscale

Tags: javascript, css, npm

I'm trying to include the Sassy Modular Scale project into my build by using [eyeglass](https://github.com/sass-eyeglass/eyeglass). I was able to get it Modular Scale via the terminal by executing the command  `npm install modularscale-sass --save-dev` in my project directory.

Then I took a look in my `package.json` and I saw that `"modularscale-sass": "^2.1.1"` was added and in my directory I could access the files under the `node-modules` directory. All good! Then the [documentation for modular scale](https://github.com/modularscale/modularscale-sass) instructs me to `@import 'modular-scale'` in my `main.scss` file.

Now I run `gulp watch` and edit some random css and see if gulp complains about any errors and I get a throw error saying

`Error: src/scss/main.scss
  6:9`  file to import not found or unreadable: `modular-scale`

I know this is happening bc gulp has no idea where to find `modular-scale` because eyeglass is prob not set up right atm.

```
protfolio/ 
|
|-- dest/
|    |-- /js
|    |-- /css
|
|-- node_modules
|   |-- modularscale-sass
|   | .. 
|
|-- src/
|    |-- /js
|    |-- /scss
|        |-- /modules
|            |-- .. 
|        |-- /partails
|            |-- ..  
|        |-- /vendors
|            |-- ..
|        |-- main.scss 
|
|-- gulpfile.js 
| ..
```

Must I edit the `eyeglass-exports.js` file?

By looking at the js code I think that the most logical thing to do would be for me to add my directory name and stylesheet. My hypothesis is that the `module.exports` function will return a path for eyeglass to locate my directory name and stylesheets. Correct?

```
var path = require('path');
// add my directory and stylesheet? 
module.exports = function(eyeglass, sass) {
  return {
    sassDir: path.join(__dirname, 'stylesheets')
  }
}
```

I found some documentation on eyeglass but it seems quite vague here:

In Sass files, you can reference the eyeglass module with standard Sass import syntax: `@import "my_eyeglass_module/file";`. The `my_eyeglass_module` will be resolved to the correct directory in your node modules, and the file will then resolve using the standard import rules for Sass.

Can someone please help explain how I to get this to work property.

Here's the link to my directory on [github](https://github.com/kapena/portfolioSite)

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

As much as I'd like to use eyeglass I feel like it's just not very clearly  documented as in it's hard to set up for someone who's new to using gulp and npm. I would like to see these docs be a little more friendly to beginners like myself.

I did my very best to follow the [Gulp integration guide](https://github.com/sass-eyeglass/eyeglass/blob/master/docs/integrations/gulp.md) however I was still getting errors that I had no idea how to deal with when I asked gulp to watch for changes.

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var sass = require("gulp-sass");
var Eyeglass = require("eyeglass").Eyeglass;

var eyeglass = new Eyeglass({
  // ... node-sass options
    importer: function(uri, prev, done) {
        done(sass.compiler.types.NULL);
    }
});


// Disable import once with gulp until we
// figure out how to make them work together.

// How do I get them to work together? This is confusing.

eyeglass.enableImportOnce = false

gulp.task("sass", function () {
  gulp.src("./sass/**/*.scss")
    .pipe(sass(eyeglass.sassOptions()).on("error", sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest("./css"));
});
```

As I said in my comment above I was quite confused as what you mean by saying disable import once with gulp until we figure out how to make them work together. My question is how do I get them to work together? I have no clue..

To pin point my main issue it's trying to get gulp to sync with eyeglass so I can retrieve modular-scale. This process confuses me a little and I would really like to see how it should be done.

Can you please set up a working Github repo with all that is required to get this work properly.

To solve my original issue which was to get modularscale into my project I just decided to do it the old school way. Can't go wrong.

So I went ahead and downloaded the zip file for [modularscale.sass](https://github.com/modularscale/modularscale-sass/releases/tag/v2.1.1) then I `@import "vendors/modular-scale";`into my `main.scss` file and all is working and good to go when I ask gulp to watch for changes.

Answer (score 1):

How have you configured gulp to know to use eyeglass? Did you Read the [gulp integration guide](https://github.com/sass-eyeglass/eyeglass/blob/master/docs/integrations/gulp.md)?

Comment: No I did not configure gulp to use eyeglass.  I'll follow your handy gulp integration guide. Can you please explain what you mean by the comment `// Disable import once with gulp until we figure out how to make them work together.` `eyeglass.enableImportOnce = false`

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what you mean by figuring out how to make them work together?

Comment: I tried setting up the gulp file as you show in your documentation but I ran into some issues there also. Not sure how to resolve this. Going to just use another route.

Comment: As much as I'd like to use eyeglass I feel like it'

Answer (score 1):

Using **eyeglass v0.8.3**, this worked for me.

Here's what I have:

#### gulpfile.js

```
// gulpfile.js
// node_modules requires
...
eyeglass       = require('eyeglass'),
...

// after all requires, setup eyeglass options
var options = eyeglass({
    sassOptions: {
        errLogToConsole: true,
        outputStyle: 'expanded'
    },
    eyeglass: {
        enableImportOnce: false
    },
    importer: function(uri, prev, done) {
        done(sass.compiler.types.NULL);
    }
});

// inside my gulp sass task
...
.pipe(sass(options).on('error', sass.logError))
```

#### main.scss

```
@import "modular-scale";
```

The only *issue* was the console warning that the `modular-scale` module did not declare a `needs` property in the `package.json`. I was also able to import the `normalize-scss` module, so this technique definitely works for those two modules.